# How to have mulpiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin URLs at once?

Tags: cross-domain

```
blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'bar.foo | foo.bar ', but only one is allowed.
```

How can I solve this? Or is it generally not used that way? If so why?
I know I could go the simple "If else" route but this seems not like a very verbose solution. Something like this:

```
if (origin.startsWith("foo")){
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://foo.bar');
} 
...
```